# Stripe payment gateway:how to test subscription testing

Tags: javascript, express, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement stripe payment gateway in my application with subscription API.

For testing the subscription

> A common need is to test how your integration handles trial periods
>   without waiting a full trial period to see the results. There’s a
>   quick solution here: create a new subscription with a trial_end value
>   only a few minutes in the future.

In order to do that I am setting the `trial_end` with the timestamp of 5 minutes in future

eg:

```
stripe.subscriptions.create({
        customer:customer.id,
        billing:'charge_automatically',
        items: [{plan: req.stripePlanId}],
        trial_end:Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000)+300
      })
```

But the webhook event `charge.succeeded` is not triggering